# Excluding duplicates from a string in results

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net, capturing-group

I am trying to amend this regex so that it does not match duplicates.

**Current regex**:

```
[\""].+?[\""]|[^ ]+
```

**Sample string**:

```
".doc" "test.xls", ".doc","me.pdf", "test file.doc"
```

**Expected results**:

```
".doc"
"test.xls"
"me.pdf"
```

**But not**

```
".doc"
"test.xls"
".doc"
"me.pdf"
```

**Note**:

1. Filenames could potentially have spaces e.g. `test file.doc`
2. items could be separated by a space or a comma or both
3. strings could have quotes around or NOT have quotes around e.g. `.doc` or `".doc"`.

Comment: can the filenames have spaces? try `("[^"\s]+")(?!.*\1)` https://regex101.com/r/qBhkPM/1

Comment: yes filenames could potentially have spaces in.

Comment: Which language did you select in RegexBuddy? In what tool or language do you want to use the pattern?

Comment: sorted issue in RegexBuddy was wrong setting!  so just need to amend it to support filenames that could have spaces and I think it will be fine - thanks

Comment: also can it also like original regex cope if some strings not quoted e.g.

Comment: ".doc" "test.xls", ".doc", "me.pdf" .xls dave.doc

Comment: Note sure if lookarounds are supported, but perhaps `(?<!\S)("[^"]+"|[^\s"]+)(?=(?:,? |$))(?!.* \1)`https://regex101.com/r/AogrRL/1

Comment: That works great for quoted and unquoted and also for filenames with spaces, just one issue it doesn't get handle duplicates if one is quote and one is not - is that at all possible? appreciate your help e.g. ".doc" "test.xls" test.xls

Comment: finally original also coped if entries separated with a comma OR a space

Comment: What's the @ sign for? Is that a language-specific thing?

Comment: Beside the point, but you know `[\""]` is equivalent to `"`, right?

Comment: IMHO regex is the wrong tool for this. You should use a parser.

Comment: @removed, not sure why it was there!.  No I didn't know [\""] is equivalent to ", but I do now!.   Fair comment, this is in C# so if better way to do it then please advise

Comment: You should have mentioned at once, that it's C# (.Net), then you would get more precise answers!

Comment: I think this is a bit closer and might be simplified, but it is not very pretty https://regex101.com/r/uB7xhQ/1 But I think a non regex solution might be a better option.

Comment: okay thanks, I see what you mean.  I think I could work with previous idea e.g. (?<!\S)("[^"]+"|[^\s"]+)(?=(?:,? |$))(?!.* \1)   -   but with one change, it works if space between words e.g. word word and if a comma and space e.g. word, word, but need it to do just comma as well e.g. word,word

Comment: It would be simple using LINQ: `var t = sampleString.Split(new char[] { ' ', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(u => u.Trim('\"')).Distinct().Select(v => '"' + v + '"').ToList();`.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, but doesn't cope with file names with spaces in e.g. "test file.doc"

Comment: @DarrenRose Oops, I missed that requirement. Can the values include double-quotes too? Can they include commas?

Comment: @Andrew Morton - Not likely to have double-quotes in, more than happy to see your solution if you have one to compare, but think I may have it working with solution below from MSDN forum response

Comment: ```string teststring = @""".doc"" ""test.xls"", "".doc"",""me.pdf"" .doc ""my file.txt""";

string pattern = @"(?nx)\G(((?>""(?'v'[^""]*?)""|(?'v'[^, ]+))(?!.*?\k<v>)|(?>""(?'o'[^""]*?)""|(?'o'[^, ]+)))(\s*,\s*|\s+|$))*";

IEnumerable<string> distinct_values =
 Regex
  .Matches( teststring, pattern )
  .Cast<Match>( )
  .SelectMany( m => m.Groups["v"].Captures.Cast<Capture>( ) )
  .Select( c => c.Value );```

Comment: p.s. and no they won't contain commas, only time comma used is as a separator

Comment: Thanks Wiktor Stribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#, you may use a simple regex to extract all valid matches and use `.Distinct()` to only keep unique values.

The regex is simple:

```
"(?<ext>[^"]+)"|(?<ext>[^\s,]+)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%22%28%3F%3Cext%3E%5B%5E%22%5D%2B%29%22%7C%28%3F%3Cext%3E%5B%5E%5Cs%2C%5D%2B%29&i=%22.doc%22%20%22test.xls%22%2C%20%22.doc%22%2C%22me.pdf%22%2C%20%22test%20file.doc%22.doc%20%22.doc%22), you only need Group "ext" values.

**Details**

- `"(?<ext>[^"]+)"` - `"`, (group "ext") any 1+ chars other than `"` and then `"`
- `|` - or
- `(?<ext>[^\s,]+)` - (group "ext") 1+ chars other than whitespace and comma

The [C# code](https://ideone.com/8eL3xR) snippet:

```
var text = "\".doc\" \"test.xls\", \".doc\",\"me.pdf\", \"test file.doc\".doc \".doc\"";
Console.WriteLine(text); // => ".doc" "test.xls", ".doc","me.pdf", "test file.doc".doc ".doc"
var pattern = "\"(?<ext>[^\"]+)\"|(?<ext>[^\\s,]+)";
var results = Regex.Matches(text, pattern)
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(x => x.Groups["ext"].Value)
        .Distinct();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", results));
```

Output:

```
.doc
test.xls
me.pdf
test file.doc
```